# Bootstrap flexbox, 2 row, 1 column layout and align contents

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I want to have a full width 2 row, "1 column" layout, that takes up the entire viewport. The top row should have it's contents on the bottom of that row, and the bottom row should have it's contents on the top of that row.

Using some examples from bootstrap, I was able to achieve this: https://codepen.io/afagard/pen/QWpJWze

However, **I am not sure if I am doing it correctly even though it looks as expected**. Specifically, I tried to set the container to `100vh` but that did not result in any changes to flexboxes so I've got each row at `50vh`. I mostly do backend work and am trying to learn flexboxes.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "I tried to set the container to 100vh but that did not result in any changes to flexboxes." What difference is that supposed to make?

Comment: That looks perfectly fine to me based on your question. Though I dont think columns and rows are really needed as you are only using 1 column. Could just have 2 divs stacked on top of eachother

Comment: @Spectric if i just make the container 100vh, the rows don't become 50vh. but i suppose i should have made the rows `height:50%` and that would have worked.

Comment: @RichardHpa using bootstrap grid? and getting the same row content alignment as shown?

Comment: Could you maybe draw up an image of what you are actually wanting to achieve?

Comment: @RichardHpa visually: the same as what is shown in the codepen.

Comment: @Alex: I agree with Richard that have some thing visually. May be I can help you with https://excalidraw.com/. PLease use this and share the url. 
However, as per my understanding, I did something https://codepen.io/afagard/pen/QWpJWze . Are you looking for soemthing like this ?

Comment: sure i added the image, thank you for the link. i suppose i am worrying about nothing if people don't see a problem with my approach.

Comment: There are many ways to solve a problem. If you have 50% height always then your solution looks okay. I would suggest to use classes as much as possible from bootstrap. My approach of solving this : 
https://codepen.io/afagard/pen/QWpJWze
I thought to justify center and then using full width columns and then aligning them as it want. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a flexbox solution using just the bootstrap classes and no additional css:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid p-0 vh-100 d-flex flex-column text-center">
  
  <div class="flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column bg-primary">
    <div class="mt-auto">
      Top half
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column bg-secondary">
    <div class="mb-auto">
      Bottom half
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```